# multiple innerjoins with linq

Tags: sql, linq, inner-join

I've got the following sql statement and need to know how to write it in linq, but i can't figure out how to write the multiple inner joins

```
SELECT Zugehörigkeiten.PK_Dept_ID
FROM mitarbeiter
    INNER JOIN (abteilungen
        INNER JOIN Zugehoerigkeiten
        ON abteilungen.PK_Dept_ID = Zugehoerigkeiten.PK_Dept_ID)
    ON mitarbeiter.MA_ID = Zugehoerigkeiten.MA_ID
WHERE (((Zugehörigkeiten.MA_ID)=1));
```

Thats what i've got:

```
var erg = from mitarbeiter
          join abteilungen
          join Zugehoerigkeiten on abteilungen.PK_Dept_ID equals zugehoerigkeiten.PK_Dept_ID on mitarbeiter.MA_ID equals Zugehoerigkeiten.MA_ID
          where zugehoerigkeiten.MA_ID=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `from <some collection>` in the linq query

Also, to join on multiple values, you need to create new anonymous objects, because you're only allowed to have a single `on <foo> equals <bar>`

```
var erg = from mitarbeiter in mitarbeiters
          join a in abteilungen
          join z in Zugehoerigkeiten 
              on new { a.PK_Dept_ID, mitarbeiter.MA_ID }
              equals new { z.PK_Dept_ID, z.MA_ID }
          where zugehoerigkeiten.MA_ID=1
          select ...
```

Sometimes it can be much simpler though. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442967/how-do-you-do-multiple-inner-joins-in-linq-to-entities) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881633/linq-filter-collection-with-ef/1882578#1882578) answer.