# How can I call Include in Entity Framework after filter query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying call Include and loading related entities in EF !after WHERE query. How can I do this in EF? In SQL it's looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT * FROM T WHERE ... (filtering data)) as T2 ON T1.A = T2.A (loading data to filtered data)
```

If i write  `db.Include(..).Where(..)` or `db.Where(..).Include(..)` , in SQL server profiler I will see next query:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM   T1 AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN T2 AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[A] = [Extent2].[A]
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[A] = [Extent3].[A]
WHERE N'B1' = [Extent1].[B]
```

But in this first performed join query and after filtering query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Materialize entity framework query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011515/materialize-entity-framework-query). EF doesn't support filtered includes, but the answer shows a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Unfortunately, this feature is not yet supported in Entity Framework (filtering on include).
Nearest you can get is to to perform separate queries.

You can check out [Larislav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3595568/337294) for more information.